# Google sheets - Replace quotation marks " " with the greek ones « » in a text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want a function that can replace ANY  " "  with the ones that we use in greece « ».

For example in A2 i have:

> The kid said "lets play" and i said "yes!".

And i want a function that will return:

> The kid said «Lets play» and i said «yes!».

(If you dont know where the greek quotation marks are located in the keyboard, then simply copy paste them and insert them in your function: « » )

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show what research have you done on that, if any? Also, won't the `CTRL + H` shortcut help with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,CHAR(34)&"(.*?)"&CHAR(34),"«$1»")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, """(.*?)""", "«$1»")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the Sheets formulae already provided, you can also make use of Apps Script:

```
function replaceQM() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let cell = ss.getRange('A1').getValue().toString();
  cell = cell.replace(/"(?=[\w,.?!\)]|$)/g, "«").replace(/(?<=[\w,.?!\)]|^)"/g, "»");  ss.getRange('A2').setValue(cell);
  console.log(cell)
}
```

The snippet above makes use of regex in order to replace the quotation marks. The first `replace` method is used to find any quotation marks at the beginning of a word and the second `replace` is used to find any quotation marks at the end of a word, taking into account the punctuation marks.

Therefore, if we run the script above, we'll be getting the following results:

[image: after running the script]

#### Reference

- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script);
- [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace);
- [Regex](https://regexr.com/).